# Ember object not being recognized

Tags: javascript, ember.js

in my project I'm using ember and it's not recognizing an object that I've created.  I created the object called

```
App.RouteSearch = App.ModuleObject.extend({ ... });
```

and when I go to create a new instance of that object I use

```
App.RouteSearch.create({"Config": null});
```

but all this does is error out and tell me "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined." Has anyone come across this before or have any idea what I could do to fix it?  Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

App.ModuleObject.extend() never returns undefined. At least if you have a App.ModuleObject that extends some Ember.Object subclass. I think that your script ordering is wrong. You are importing:

```
App.RouteSearch.create({"Config": null});
```

before then:

```
App.RouteSearch = App.ModuleObject.extend({ ... });
```

Comment: AKA the order you show above is correct, are you sure its executing in that order.

Comment: Of course this is a better explanation. Sometimes is difficult to me write some things, because english isn't my native language, and the result become confuse. Your comment is still valid @kingpin2k thanks :)